# Subring of a commutative ring with unity implies ring is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. If a subring $S$ of $R$ is an integral domain containing the unity of $R$ (that isn’t $\{0,1\}$), does this imply that $R$ is too an integral domain? I tried to find a counterexample but I did not find one:

I figured maybe the subring of $Z_{10}$, $(2)$, would work since I figured it would be isomorphic to $Z_5$ (and thus an integral domain), but then I realized it has no multiplicative identity so that’s a no.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom this doesn't contain the unit of $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$. You could instead look at the diagonal inside $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Dave oops, you are of course right! am running on v little sleep lolol

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom it's no problem, you're example is essentially right: you want to look at a copy of $\mathbb Z$ inside $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$; it's just a small detail.

Comment: In itself the ideal of $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ generated by the class of $2$ (which is I think what you meant be "$(2)$"), equipped with the restricted arithmetic operations, _does_ have a multiplicative identity, namely the class of $6$. Nonetheless it is not a subring according to most texts, since (for them) by definition a (unitary) subring must share its mutliplicative identity with the containing ring.

Comment: Every single algebra over a field contains a copy of that field... but they're not all domains...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another good class of rings for examples is polynomial rings and their quotients. For this problem, consider the subring $\mathbb C$ inside $\mathbb C[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$.

Comment: Awesome set of examples, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the implication of your title were true, it would be impossible to extend an integral domain with zero divisors. But that clearly *is* possible. For instance in $\Bbb Z[X]$ if $P,Q$ are any non-constant polynomials, their images in $\Bbb Z[X]/(PQ)$ will be zero divisors, but the quotient ring still contains (the isomorphic image of) the integral domain$~\Bbb Z$. So no, the implication does not hold.